# When will the data quality function be released to the release version

Tags: data-quality, apache-dolphinscheduler

When will the dolphinscheduler data quality function be released to the release version?
Is there a time plan for this。

Answer (score 0):

3.0-alpha has supported this feature, you can download the version from the url[1]

1,https://dolphinscheduler.apache.org/en-us/download/download.html